# USB details detection issue | using node-hid with angular and electron

Tags: node.js, angular, electron, usb, hid

I am building an desktop app using Angular 7 and Electron 7. I need to read connected USB device details. To be specific I need to read connected USB barcode scanner serial number.
Debian version of my app is working perfectly with below code:

```
var HID = require('node-hid');
var devices = HID.devices();
console.log(devices);
```

When I try this same code in Win32 version of my app, it generates this below error:

**tmp.node is not a valid Win32 application**

> ..\resources\app.asar\node_modules\express\lib\application.js:630 Error:
>   ..\AppData\Local\Temp\95434314-b7bd-4c9a-8413-b9c602346bd1.tmp.node is not a valid Win32 application.
>   ..\AppData\Local\Temp\95434314-b7bd-4c9a-8413-b9c602346bd1.tmp.node
>       at process.func [as dlopen] (electron/js2c/asar.js:155:31)
>       at Object.Module._extensions..node (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:881:18)
>       at Object.func [as .node] (electron/js2c/asar.js:164:18)
>       at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:701:32)
>       at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:633:12)
>       at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:625:3)
>       at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:739:19)
>       at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:14:16)
>       at bindings (..\AppData\Local\retailpos\app-1.0.0\resources\app.asar\node_modules\bindings\bindings.js:112:48)
>       at loadBinding (..\AppData\Local\retailpos\app-1.0.0\resources\app.asar\node_modules\node-hid\nodehid.js:25:42)

I am looking for a solve more than a week now. Can't find any solved answer.
I have checked that electron-rebuild is working properly.

- Angular: 7.*
- NPM: 6.13.1
- Node: 12.12.1
- Electron: 7.1.2
- node-hid: 1.0.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue has been solved when I created a Windows Build from a windows system. According to my understanding -  Cross origin OS build was generating that issue.

Comment: Is that possible to use node-hid in angular web application